# Dataset for a Healthcare RecSys

Tags: medical, machine-learning

i want dataset that contains ratings and/or reviews of doctors/Physicians by their patients, both doctors and patients must be identified by unique ID.. Is there any public dataset i can use for my Final Year Project?

Comment: hello  - did you ever thought to use the data that is available here: https://healthsites.io/
see healthsites.io Building an open data commons of health facility data with OpenStreetMapv  guesss that you can use the data - but i am not 100% sure see here the terms of usage over there at healthsites.io: 
. perhaps some other user can help out here and tell us if you are able to use the data!?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, i will try it and come back to you with the outcome :)

Comment: hi there - thx for the feedback - i guess that this might be interesting for you. And if you get more insights - a. into the dataset and the relevance for you and b. in the legal things -i.e. for a concrete usage for your project then just let us know if the above mentiioned ressource might be a apropiate help for your project and  helpful? - Have a great day.

Comment: dear Abdelaaziz - i have checked out and found some interesting things for you
see what the folks write on the site: cf https://healthsites.io   Open data collaboration
Through collaborations with users, trusted partners and OpenStreetMap we will capture and validate the location and contact details of every facility and make this data freely available under an Open Data License (ODBL)'  - end of citation

guess that this is good for you - - regards - hope that i could help you. All the best to you for your endeavours

Comment: Hello, thank you for the follow. I have checked the website, and i can't find the data structure i need, in fact, the important thing i want is the ratings a user give to a service (healthcare) in my case. I can't find ratings in the website healthsites.io, all i can find are informations about the healtcare provider by city or country.. That is good but i still need users/patient reviews and rating. Thank you for your help :) :)

Comment: hi there - yes i see and i agree - unfortunatley...  So i guess you need other ressources..
but afaik - THE DATA THEY HAVE - THIS DATASET IS FREE - released under creative common or some similar 
licence.. - i guess
All the best to you and your endeavours